# freeze simulation in gloss Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, simulation, gloss

I'm using the gloss library to picture a simulation. Is there a function, which stops the `simulation` function when a condition is true. Just the last drawn picture should remain in the window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about just adding another state variable to record whether or not the simulation should be frozen?

If the `isFrozen` value is `True` you just return the current model; otherwise you evolve it - i.e. apply the step function.

Answer (score 0):

As @ErikR suggested, what you're describing amounts to not updating the model anymore once you've reached the state you are looking for. You can define a combinator acting on stepping functions doing precisely this:

```
untilModel
  :: (ViewPort -> Float -> model -> model)
  -> (model -> Bool)
  -> (ViewPort -> Float -> model -> model)
untilModel step isFrozen v f m =
  if isFrozen m then m
  else step v f m
```

When you have a `step` function and you want to stop the simulation when `isFrozen` becomes true of the model, you can simply pass `simulate` the altered step function `` step `untilModel` isFrozen ``.